# How to convert a lot of videos at once in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, sound, video, transcode

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 for about two weeks. At this moment, I need to convert a lot of videos(58 to be exact!) into audio. Googling about converters, I installed Transmageddon. It's pretty cool but it converts one video at a time! 
**How can I make Transmageddon convert all those videos at once? And if I can't what's the better alternative to do so?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shell scripting to apply `Transmageddon` to each file. Something like:

```
for i in Videos/* ; do
    Transmageddon ${i}   # parameters incomplete You get to fix this
done
```